# Okta re enter password after logging in for a particular action

Tags: authentication, access-token, okta, refresh-token, okta-api

I'm using okta to sign-in to my react based web application. There is an edit action within the app that requires the user to re-enter his password. I've checked the docs and couldn't find anything similar. The closest I got to was the 're-authenticate' user part. However, that's only based on time. I want to achieve similar functionality based on an event(say, button click). Can I do this using refresh tokens? (I'm not clear about the whole idea of refresh token). Is there a workaround or a specific okta API that allows me to do this?

Comment: Okta's `/authorize` API does provide a "prompt" option, perhaps they use one of the SDK methods to trigger a new oauth redirect and pass that param? For example, `auth.redirect({prompt: true})` https://github.com/okta/okta-oidc-js/tree/master/packages/okta-react#authredirectadditionalparams

Comment: Doesn't that make the user session expire? All I want is to reverify the user's password for a specific action. If he enters a wrong password, he won't be able to perform a specific action but he still remains logged in.

Comment: I don't know, I haven't tried it myself. It was the only method I could think of. I confirmed this with the Developer Experience team at Okta that this would be the best thing to try.

Comment: I'll try that out, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have contacted Okta support and they advised me to use the Okta MFA factors(OTP to email/phone, Google Auth etc.) and not to prompt the user to enter a password.

MFA Factors API: https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/factors/